# Opening YouTube video with button click in mobile

Tags: wordpress, mobile, youtube

I've searched so much that my brain is starting to hurt. Basically, I would like for the button on my site to open a YouTube video on mobile. On desktop, it will open up a lightbox and a simple embed that autoplays. I've read that mobile devices won't allow autoplay because it eats up data. If the user is choosing a button ('Watch Now', 'Watch Video', etc.) is that not a choice to use data? Is there really no way to do an .onClick parameter?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Use the wordpress function `wp_is_mobile()`.

```
if ( wp_is_mobile() ) {
   /* Display and echo for mobile specific stuff here */

}else{
   /* Display and echo for Desktop */    

}
```

Read more about this function https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_is_mobile/